# Find the derivative using the definition derivatives: $f(x) = xH(x)$ where $H(x) = 0$ when $x < 0$ & $ H(x) = x$ when $x\ge 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My solution: the derivative doesn't come out as nicely as I had thought, can someone verify that I'm solving this properly?

Using the definition: lim $H(x)_{x\to a} = (f(x)- f(a))/(x-a)$

Which implies $\lim_{x\to 0} = (xH(x) - 0\cdot H(0))/(x-0)$

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to0} = xH(x)/x$

The $x$ terms cancel out from the numerator and denominator.

Since at $0$, $H(x) = x$

and $x = 0 $ at $ 0$,

the derivative of $xH(x) = 0$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.  $0$ is the correct answer but your method has an error.

For positive $x$, your calculation gives the wrong derivative.  $f'(x)=\frac{d(xH(x))}{dx}=H(x)\frac{dx}{dx}+x\frac{dH(x)}{dx} = H(x)+xH'(x)$ so you are missing the second term.

You have $f(x)=0$ when $x \lt 0$ and $f(x)=x^2$ when $x \ge 0$. This is continuous for all $x$ including when $x=0$.

$f'(x)=0$ when $x \lt 0$ and $f'(x)=2x$ when $x\gt0$.  So the left derivative of $f(x)$ when $x=0$ is $0$ while the right derivative of $f(x)$ when $x=0$ is $2\times 0=0$.  Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ and the left and right derivatives are equal to each other there, they give the derivative there, namely $0$.

Comment: I can sort of follow, and I would be able to come to the same conclusion if I wasn't bound to using the definition of the derivative, so my question remains how do I use the definition to arrive at the desired conclusion?

Comment: At least for positive $x$, $H(x)$ varies with $x$.  I would have the derivative as $\lim\dfrac{xH(x)-aH(a)}{x-a} = \lim\dfrac{xH(x)-aH(x)+aH(x)-aH(a)}{x-a} $ $= \lim \left(H(x)+ a \dfrac{H(x)-H(a)}{x-a} \right)$ which for this particular $H(x)$ is $H(a)+a=2a$ for positive $a$ is and is $H(a)=0$ for negative $a$.  The problem I am having explaining this is that when $a=0$ we have $0=a=2a$ so everything disappears.

Comment: Perhaps in this particular case it makes not difference which approach you take.